# mongodb aggregate function implementation in java driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to implement this aggregate query in java i have no idea what to do?

```
db.History.aggregate([ 
    { "$match" : {"thId":"001"}},
    { "$group" : { 
              "_id" : {"Id":"$Id","controller" : "$controller","mod" : "$mod","variable" : "$variable"}  
              ,"variable" : {"$first": "$$ROOT"}
              ,"data" : {"$push":{"value":"$value","updatedDateTime":"$updatedTime"}}
            }
    }
    ])
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer Mongo Java Driver [Documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/) ,

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Test");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("History");
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.append("$match",new Document("thId","001"));
        Document group = new Document();

        group.append("$group", new Document("_id",new Document().append("Id", "$Id").append("controller", "$controller").append("mod" , "$mod").append("variable" , "$variable"))
        .append("variable" , new Document("$first", "$$ROOT"))
        .append("data",new Document().append("$push", new Document().append("value", "$value").append("updatedDateTime","$updatedTime"))));
        ArrayList<Document> docList = new ArrayList<Document>();
        docList.add(doc);
        docList.add(group);

        List<Document> results =collection.aggregate(docList).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
        for(Document res: results){
            System.out.println(res.toJson());
        }
```